# Cache in GrapghQl Flutter package settings and how to check it works

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql

I'm trying to implement graphQl Flutter package in my app.

https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter

Everything works well, but I have some issues with cache.

If we ran example from this package https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/tree/master/packages/graphql_flutter/example we can see that cache doesn't work.

In my app I also can't increase speed, it always get data online.

The code from this example

```
class GraphQLWidgetScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const GraphQLWidgetScreen() : super();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
      uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
    );

    final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
      // ignore: undefined_identifier
      getToken: () async => 'Bearer $YOUR_TOKEN',
    );

    Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink);
    if (ENABLE_WEBSOCKETS) {
      final WebSocketLink websocketLink = WebSocketLink(
        url: 'ws://localhost:8080/ws/graphql',
        config: SocketClientConfig(
            autoReconnect: true, inactivityTimeout: Duration(seconds: 15)),
      );

      link = link.concat(websocketLink);
    }

    final ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient>(
      GraphQLClient(
        cache: OptimisticCache(
          dataIdFromObject: typenameDataIdFromObject,
        ),
        link: link,
      ),
    );

    return GraphQLProvider(
      client: client,
      child: const CacheProvider(
        child: MyHomePage(title: 'GraphQL Widget'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Animation that shows that cache doesn't work

[image]

So, the question is - what is the right way to implement cache and how check it works.

Thank you!

Comment: Finally I made my own cache with BLoC pattern, because didn't find how to use package for this :)

Answer (score 2):

The examples are meant to be standalone - as such they use separate clients and caches. The consequence of this is that it is [re-instantiated every mount](https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/blob/master/packages/graphql_flutter/example/lib/graphql_widget/main.dart#L38). In other words, every time you navigates to the example's route, you get a new cache, so you can't see the caching effects. For a more substantial example where you can see if the cache is working, see [the starwars example](https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/blob/master/examples/starwars/lib/main.dart) ([related github discussion](https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/issues/545))